# Database Connection available to all class files

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some confusion i think

I am trying to get my database connections to be available to functions within my class files, so that i dont need to inject it into all calls the the functions. i think this is the neatest way of doing this, but am unsure rally

(simplified) i have 3 files

1.) database connection file (using PDO)

2.) class file with all my relevant functions

3.) a file that will be mainly HTML file that includes the needed class and database connections and starts the instances required.

My (simplified/cut down) class file

```
<?php
class SPD_Products {

    // varaibales


    // start category variables
    public $CategoryID;
    public $CategoryName;
    public $CategoryDescription;
    public $CategoryActive;
    public $CategoryDateAdded;
    public $CategoryDateModified;


    /*
    * public function to set category varaiables
    * @param int $categoryID
    * @return true/false
    */
    public function setCategory($CategoryID){
        try {
            if(isset($CategoryID) && is_int($CategoryID)){
                if($result = $this->getCategoryByCategoryID($CategoryID)){

                    $this->CategoryID = intval($result->CategoryID);
                    $this->CategoryName = htmlentities($result->CategoryName);
                    $this->CategoryDescription = htmlentities($result->CategoryDescription);
                    $this->CategoryActive = intval($result->CategoryActive);
                    $this->CategoryDateAdded = intval($result->CategoryDateAdded);
                    $this->CategoryDateModified = intval($result->CategoryDateModified);

                }
                else {
                    return 'No Category';
                }           
            }
            else {
                return false;       
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e){       
            error_log('file = '.__FILE__.'.php class = '.get_class($this).' - function = '.__FUNCTION__.' - Exception caught: '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;   
        }

    }




    /* ================================================================ */
    /* ======================== SQL Queries =========================== */
    /* ================================================================ */


    /*
    * public function to get all category details by CategoryID
    * @param int $CategoryID
    * @return array of results
    */  
    public function getCategoryByCategoryID($CategoryID) {
        try{
            global $db;

            $query = "SELECT c.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, c.CategoryDescription, c.CategoryActive, c.CategoryDateAdded, c.CategoryDateModified, c.CategoryShopAvailable
                        FROM tCategories c                      
                    WHERE c.CategoryID = ?
                    AND c.CategoryActive = 1
                    AND c.CategoryShopAvailable = 1";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array($CategoryID));             
            return $stmt->Fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex){
            error_log('file = '.__FILE__.'.php class = '.get_class($this).' - function = '.__FUNCTION__.' - Exception caught: '.$ex->getMessage());
            echo 'file = '.__FILE__.'.php class = '.get_class($this).' - function = '.__FUNCTION__.' - Exception caught: '.$ex->getMessage();
            return false;       
        }   
    }

}
?>
```

My database connection file

```
// database login details
//* Define these so that they can't be changed
DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'xxxxx');
DEFINE ('DBPASS', 'xxxxx');
DEFINE ('DBHOST', '192.168.0.99');
DEFINE ('DBPORT', '3999');
DEFINE ('DBNAME', 'xxxxx');

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.'; port='.DBPORT.'; dbname='.DBNAME.'; charset=utf8', DBUSER, DBPASS);       
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 


}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo 'An Error occured! '.$ex->getMessage(); //user friendly message    
    error_log('dbconn.php failed to connect to db - Exception caught: '.$ex->getMessage());
    return false;
}
?>
```

my test page

```
<?php
require_once('functions/dbconn.php');
require_once('class/products.class.php'); 

//$db = new Database(); // failed test
$products_obj = new SPD_Products();

$products_obj->setCategory($CategoryID = 1);
echo $products_obj->CategoryName;

?>
```

I have tried various ways of getting the database connection into the class, but only the global method works, (which i dont think it s good or neat idea...). The above does work but i want a better way....
I will eventually have lots of separate class files, so dont want to make a new connection in each class file, as i am sure i can do this only once without using the global and without the need to keep injecting it and passing it from function to function.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this, put your login credential into a php file:

```
<?php
// database login details
$config = array('DBUSER'=>'xxxxx',
                'DBPASS'=>'xxxxx',
                'DBHOST'=>'192.168.0.99',
                'DBPORT'=>'3999'
                'DBNAME'=> 'xxxxx');

?>
```

then turn `dbconn.php` into a class, this will make it easier:

```
<?php
class DB {

   function __construct() {
      //some config here
      require_once('functions/config.php');
   }

   function get_connection() {
    try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['DBHOST'].'; port='.$config['DBPORT'].'; dbname='.$config['DBNAME'].'; charset=utf8'
                  , $config['DBUSER'], $config['DBPASS']);        
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo 'An Error occured! '.$ex->getMessage(); //user friendly message    
        error_log('dbconn.php failed to connect to db - Exception caught: '.$ex->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return $db;
   }
}
?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
class SPD_Products {

   require_once('functions/dbconn.php');
   private $conn;
   ....
   function __construct() {
        $db = new DB();
        $this->conn = $db->get_connection();
   }

    public function getCategoryByCategoryID($CategoryID) {
        try{
            $query = "....";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);//here
        .......
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex){
           .....
            return false;       
        }   
    }

}
?>
```

---

This is just q quick way, but of course you can add more logic, such as checking if connection is open before creating a new one , etc.... you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks!! i have tried it, and have tryed very similar before, but i keep getting this error Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare()  i do howver have a DB connection in $this->conn (i think)

Comment: Oops i forgot to add $this in the constructor check it again